# How to change a border of ToolBarPanel in WPF APP?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a toolbarpanel but it doesnt provide property border, borderbrush, etc. Also it doesnt provide property "ControlTemplate" to customize it.
How to change a border of ToolBarPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToolBarPanel is a panel, meaning it has no visual appearance -- this is why there's no template for it.  You can, however, add whatever you want wherever you want inside the ToolBarPanel via its Children member.  To create a border, just add the desired Border as the only direct child of the ToolBarPanel, add a Grid as the child of the Border, and then add your content that you wanted displayed in the ToolBarPanel inside the Grid.